# Get a list of tags and get the attribute values in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to use BeautifulSoup so get a list of HTML `<div>` tags, then check if they have a name attribute and then return that attribute value. Please see my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) #assume html contains <div> tags with a name attribute
nameTags = soup.findAll('name') 
for n in nameTags:
    if n.has_key('name'):
       #get the value of the name attribute
```

My question is how do I get the value of the name attribute?

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code, it should work

```
nameTags = soup.findAll('div',{"name":True})
for n in nameTags:
    # Do your processing
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, your above code will work but I would like to know how to get the value of the attribute

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all figured it out

```
n['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here is the code to use as a single answer:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameTags = soup.findAll('div',{"name":True})
for n in nameTags:
    name = n['name']
    # Do your processing
```

Passing a second argument of `{"name":True}` limits the results to `div` tags that have a `name` attribute. If you were looking for tags that had a specific value for the `name` tag, you could pass `{"name":"specificNameValue"}`