# Getting HTML Input Field value with Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my function:

```
def fetchIframe(vid_url):
    r = requests.get(vid_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    iframe_link = soup.find("input", {"id": "mediaEmbedCodeInput", "type": "text"}).get(['value'])

return iframe_link
```

The vid_url is valid, I've begun testing in the python console and I keep getting this error when I run the above function. I haven't found much documentation relating to this. I must be looking in the wrong places and asking the wrong question.

Here is the error:

```
iframe_link = soup.find('input', {'name':'media_embed_code'}).get('value')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And I've tried to remedy the situation by using the methods of value display from this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797741/beautifulsoup-get-a-list-of-tags-and-get-the-attribute-values).

I feel I'm over-complicating my issue but at the moment I can't see a way to resolve this. I realize that my iframe_link object has a NoneType but why is this?

Comment: can you post the value of soup?

Comment: resolved the problem, my link generation was causing the error after all, I missed the problem initially

Answer (score 1):

The error actually occurred due to a link generation mix-up, thanks to @user2954587 to remind me to check the soup!